# Why Sonar analyzer reports a possible connection leak in the PreparedStatement close

Tags: java, sonarqube, resource-leak

I have a code that looks like this,

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
ResultSet rs1 = null;

try{
   con = <someConnectionPool>.getConnection();
   ps1 = con.prepareStatement(<someSQLString>);
   rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
  
   while(rs1.next()){
       PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
       ResultSet rs2 = null;          
       try{
          ps2 = con.prepareStatement(<someOtherSQLString>); // Sonar reports this prepared statement is not closed
          rs2 = ps2.executeQuery(); // But no issue for this result set
          while(rs2.next()){
             System.out.println(rs2.getString(<someColumnName>));
          }
       }finally{
          if(rs2 != null) rs2.close();
          if(ps2 != null) ps2.close(); // But here, I am closing the ps2
       }
   }

}catch(Exception e){
  // Exception logging here
}finally{
   if(rs1 != null) rs1.close();
   if(ps1 != null) ps1.close();
   if(con != null && !con.isClosed()) con.close();
}
```

I am confused whether there is actually connection leak is there or is this some false positive reporting. And, as I have mentioned in the code, `rs2` result set does **NOT** get reported as an issue. Only the prepared statement `ps2` gets reported.

Comment: You can try using `try-with-resources` instead of manually closing them. Maybe it solves the issue.

Comment: Yes, that is what Sonar also suggests as the compliant solution. But, what is the issue in the above code

Answer (score 1):

The problem with above code is in the `finally` block, if either `rs1` or `ps1` throw exception, `con1` might not able to close. If you able to use Java 7 and above then consider using `try-with-resources`. If running on Java 1.6 and below then proper way should look like

```java
   if(rs1 != null) try {rs1.close();}catch(Exception e){//handle the given exception}
   if(ps1 != null) try{ps1.close();}catch(Exception e){//handle the given exception}
   if(con != null && !con.isClosed()) try {con.close();}catch(Exception e){//handle the given exception}
```

Comment: I do not think that is the reason, if so, why the Sonar won't report about closing the result set.

Answer (score 1):

The [java.sql.ResultSet#close()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) method may throw an exception:

> SQLException - if a database access error occurs

If the following line

```
if(rs2 != null) rs2.close();
```

throws an exception, then `ps2` is never closed.

I think there are a few things which could be improved in your code. First of all according to the `ResultSet` class JavaDoc:

> A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed by the `Statement` object that generated it when that `Statement` object is closed, re-executed, or is used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

It means your code could be changed to:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps1 = null;

try {
   con = <someConnectionPool>.getConnection();
   ps1 = con.prepareStatement(<someSQLString>);
   final ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
  
   while (rs1.next()) {
       PreparedStatement ps2 = null;       
       try {
          ps2 = con.prepareStatement(<someOtherSQLString>);
          final ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
          while (rs2.next()) {
             System.out.println(rs2.getString(<someColumnName>));
          }
       } finally {
          if (ps2 != null) ps2.close();
       }
   }

} catch (Exception e) {
  // Exception logging here
} finally {
   if (ps1 != null) ps1.close();
   if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) con.close();
}
```

Next we need to make sure that connection is also always closed too:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps1 = null;

try {
   con = <someConnectionPool>.getConnection();
   ps1 = con.prepareStatement(<someSQLString>);
   final ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
  
   while (rs1.next()) {
       PreparedStatement ps2 = null;       
       try {
          ps2 = con.prepareStatement(<someOtherSQLString>);
          final ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
          while (rs2.next()) {
             System.out.println(rs2.getString(<someColumnName>));
          }
       } finally {
          if (ps2 != null) ps2.close();
       }
   }

} catch (Exception e) {
  // Exception logging here
} finally {
   try {
       if (ps1 != null) ps1.close();
   } finally {
       if (con != null) con.close();
   }
}
```

This code works exactly as yours - when any `close` method throws an exception, it is also thrown by your method. I changed

```
if(con != null && !con.isClosed()) con.close();
```

to

```
if (con != null) con.close();
```

because ([read JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#close()))

> Calling the method `close` on a `Connection` object that is already closed is a no-op.

It is also possible to rewrite `try-catch` to [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) but I don't know which Java version you use.